# How to make pmount using big_writes option for ntfs-3g mouting?

Tags: mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

using pmount to conveniently mount usb disks, some are ntfs.
by default pmount do ntfs-3g mounting without `big_writes` option.
how to config pmount so it use `big_writes` option for ntfs-3g?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? `pmount` shouldn't be necessary as `udisks2` is in place by default 

Comment: @matigo Thx for advice, but me not familiar with `udisks2` (nor for `pmount`, but at least already some using experience of it). Seems with udisks, need to put some config into `/etc/udev/rules.d`, which is trying to avoid. Personally, pmount is very convinient for occasional usage, while usdisk2 is better if the user has write permission in `/etc`.